# How to configure cmake project for linux header files

Tags: c, linux

Kernel version: `5.19.0-38-generic`

I have installed `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

After i include `module.h` I get a lot of errors

```
#include <linux/module.h>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

For example:

`rwonce.h:64:8: error: unknown type name '__no_sanitize_or_inline'`

But in `compiler_types.h` lines with this type definition are commented

```
# define __no_kasan_or_inline __no_sanitize_address notrace __maybe_unused
# define __no_sanitize_or_inline __no_kasan_or_inline
#else
# define __no_kasan_or_inline __always_inline
#endif
```

My CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(testproj C)
include_directories("/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic/include/")
include_directories("/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic/arch/x86/include/")
include_directories("/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic/arch/x86/include/generated")
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(testproj main.c)
```

Comment: Careful! These days, most distros (e.g. fedora, ubuntu) put "cleaned up" copies of the `linux` [and `asm`] `.h` files under `/usr/include`: in (e.g.) `/usr/include/linux` and `/usr/include/asm`. These may conflict with ones you install. Generally, unless your program needs `.h` files that are _not_ already provided or needs the "unadulterated" versions, you don't need to do this.

Comment: `/usr/include/linux/module.h` has only two `#define` because 99.44% of it isn't useful for an app--only for a custom kernel module you might create. But, if you're trying to build a module, you may need the full linux source tree to have access to the module build process/scripts. So, you may need the [skeletal] `/usr/src/kernels/*` to have enough to build a module or something from kernel.org or the git repo for the kernel source, etc.